# How to run filestack in Internet explorer or Microsoft edge?

Tags: angular, typescript, web-applications, ngx-bootstrap

https://github.com/lahirusamishka/filestack-test   this is "ngx rocket" angular project. I added the https://www.npmjs.com/package/@filestack/angular  this library and open file stack dialog box as well. but is file upload progress not showing and exit the file stack return the file upload fail object. I need to fix this. anybody suggest me idea to that project.